# How to filter an array of objects (with arrays inside) with another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have these two arrays:

```
filters:
        {
            location: ['Swiss cottage','Fulham'],
            age: ['Giga'],
        }
```

and

```
data: 
[
  {
    "location": "Swiss cottage",
    "ages": "Giga",
  },
  {
    "location": "Fulham",
    "ages": "Kilo",
  },
  {
    "location": "Putney",
    "ages": "Micro",
  }
]
```

I want to use the first one to filter the second, how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. If it's either one of the filters, change `&&` to `||`.

```js
let filters = {
    location: ['Swiss cottage','Fulham'],
    age: ['Giga'],
}

let data= [
  {
    "location": "Swiss cottage",
    "ages": "Giga",
  },
  {
    "location": "Fulham",
    "ages": "Kilo",
  },
  {
    "location": "Putney",
    "ages": "Micro",
  }
]

let x = data.filter(d => {
  if (filters.location.includes(d.location) && filters.age.includes(d.ages))
    return d;
});
 
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries of `filters` for having an iterable data set and filter `data` by checking every key of the entries with the value.

As result you get only the object who match for all properties of the `filter`.

This approach requires the same property names for `filter` and `data`.

**AND approach with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)**

All searched properties must match.

```js
var filters = { location: ['Swiss cottage', 'Fulham'], ages: ['Giga'] },
    data = [{ location: "Swiss cottage", ages: "Giga" }, { location: "Fulham", ages: "Kilo" }, { location: "Putney", ages: "Micro" }],
    entries = Object.entries(filters),
    result = data.filter(o => entries.every(([k, v]) => v.includes(o[k])));

console.log(result);
```

**OR approach with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)**

One searched property must match.

```js
var filters = { location: ['Swiss cottage', 'Fulham'], ages: ['Giga'] },
    data = [{ location: "Swiss cottage", ages: "Giga" }, { location: "Fulham", ages: "Kilo" }, { location: "Putney", ages: "Micro" }],
    entries = Object.entries(filters),
    result = data.filter(o => entries.some(([k, v]) => v.includes(o[k])));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filters = {
    location: ['Swiss cottage','Fulham'],
    age: ['Giga'],
};

const data = [
  {
    "location": "Swiss cottage",
    "ages": "Giga",
  },
  {
    "location": "Fulham",
    "ages": "Kilo",
  },
  {
    "location": "Putney",
    "ages": "Micro",
  }
];

const output = data.filter(item => {
   return filters.location.indexOf(item.location) > -1 && filters.age.indexOf(item.ages) > -1;
});

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, the arrays in the "filters" object need to include the corresponding values.

```
let filteredData = data.filter((x) => 
        filters.location.includes(x.location) && 
        filters.age.includes(x.ages));
```